# sigma algebra and the powerset of N

Tags: measure-theory

I have a problem on measure theory. I find it hard to characterize a the powerset of natural numbers:

Let $S = \mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathcal{F}=\{\{n, n+1,...\} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$

I am aware that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\pi$-system, but I am not sure how this can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a $\pi$-system by the way? And why did you think that would help?

Comment: definition:
A collection $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{P}(S)$ is called a $\pi$-system if $\forall A,B \in \mathcal{E}$ one has $A \cap B \in \mathcal{E}$.

This was the first part of the problem. The second part is the one in the question. I thought I had to think in that direction.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for telling me the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $F_k=\{k,k+1,\cdots\}$. By your definition, $F_k \in \mathcal{F}$.

A sigma algebra is closed under intersection and taking compliments.

Therefore, for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$: $F_k - F_{k+1} = F_k \cap F_{k+1}^c=\{k\} \in \sigma(\mathcal{F})$.

Every non-empty subset of $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ can be represented as a at most countable union of its elements, $A = \bigcup_{k\in A} \{k\}$. Since each $k$ is a natural number and we just showed $\{k\} \in \sigma{\mathcal(F)}$, by the closure of a sigma algebra with respect to countable unions, $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{F})$.

In other words, $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ contains every non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$. In particular, it contains $\mathbb{N}$ and therefore, it contains $\emptyset$ too.  Hence, $\sigma(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is the power set of natural numbers.